# lambda function creation for assignment

Tags: python, lambda

I'm trying to make the following into a lambda function

```
lambda x: a_vector.gf_multiply_modular(x_vector, modulus, n) ^ b_vector where x_vector=BitVector.BitVector(bitstring=x)
```

So basically "do something with new assigned value" where "new assigned value is some transformation done on the input" How woudl I do thta?

Comment: Why are you trying to put something verbose like this in to a lambda?

Comment: I'm voting "unclear what you're asking" because your description is a mix of valid-looking Python syntax and invalid stuff, and because it's not clear at all why you want a lambda (even after your last comment, which makes no sense to me).

Comment: Why do you need to return a lambda? Why can't you just write a function?

Comment: Assignment is a *statement*, not an expression. You can't use statements in an expression; statements contain expressions, not the other way around. It is entirely unclear what you are trying to achieve however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *must* have a lambda, would

```
lambda x: a_vector.gf_multiply_modular(BitVector.BitVector(bitstring=x), modulus, n) ^ b_vector
```

give you the result you require?